# Organizing results using ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

Right now I am using an sql query that looks as such.

```
SELECT 
'Name',
'Department' 
UNION ALL tb1.Name, 
tb2.Department FROM tb1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2 ON 
tb1.MyIndex = tb2.MyIndex 
ORDER BY Name, Department ASC;
```

The dilema that I am having is that the ordering is not really working the way I need it to. I need the headers to stay at the top of my query for export sake and also my department is not ordering correctly. My output looks like this.

```
David   |    1
Joe     |    1
Phil    |    3
George  |    2
Name    | Department
```

Now when I take the headers out I can sort by the column without incident

```
SELECT tb1.Name, tb2.Department
FROM tb1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2 ON
tb1.MyIndex = tb2.MyIndex
ORDER BY tb1.Name, tb2.Department
```

And my output will look good.

```
David   |    1
Joe     |    1
George  |    2
Phil    |    3
```

Except for one thing, this query finishes with

```
INTO OUTFILE 'file.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' LINES
TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

When I'm importing this file, I need the headers, however when I put the headers in I have to search on the header and not the Column name, and the ORDER BY doesnt even work properly, so my question is how do I Order the resuts to

```
ORDER BY tb1.Name, tb2.Department
```

so that my results will look like my second set of results In this post but have headers included?

Comment: Why do you use `UNION` anyway? Just to have the column names hardcoded in your query? There has to be a different way.

Comment: If you know of another way to put column names in a CSV file from mysql without union I'm all ears, all I've ever seen is with a union.

Comment: I'd you a controlling language like shell commands or PHP or Perl ... that start a m MySQL query. This gets the proper header texts automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a sub-query:

```
SELECT 
  'Name' as header1,
  'Department' as header2 
UNION ALL 
select 
  suq_query.Name,
  suq_query.Department
from
(
  select tb1.Name, 
    tb2.Department 
  FROM tb1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.MyIndex = tb2.MyIndex 
  ORDER BY Name ASC, Department ASC
) as suq_query
INTO OUTFILE 'file.txt' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' LINES
TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver, well maybe thats a bit melodramatic but your logic worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

To do this correctly, you should NOT depend on the order of the output from a union.  Instead, be explicit:

```
select name, department
from (SELECT 'Name' as name, 'Department' as department, 1 as isheader
      UNION ALL
      SELECT tb1.Name, tb2.Department, 0 as isheader
      FROM tb1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2
           ON tb1.MyIndex = tb2.MyIndex
     ) t
ORDER BY isheader desc, tb1.Name, tb2.Department+0
```

Just to be clear, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) says:

> However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies
>   nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result
>   because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.

Comment: This might still order `Department` as a string instead of number.

Comment: @Vatev . . . Very good point.  I fixed the query.  In MySQL, you can just add 0 to a string to convert it to a number, which is quite sufficient for the order by.  (And, if the string is not a number, it is converted to 0.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I knew that UNION ALL was what was causing the problem I just didn't know how/couldn't find a good answer to this in the internet. I wish I could mark two answers for this one but I'll at least +1. Ty